# Report Builder expression SQL list certain values only

Tags: sql, report, expression, builder, iif

In report builder i'm trying to only get the values containing 'Office' from the software list.

```
=Fields!Software.Value
```

This will get the entire list of all installed software but i want to list the values with "Office".

I have tried something like :

```
=Fields!Software.Value = "Office"
=IIF(Fields!Software.Value = "Office", Fields!Software.Value)
```

Can't seem to figure out how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Filter expression:

```
=Join(Filter(Fields!Software.Value,"Office"),",")
```

I added Join so you can display the list in Text Box.

If you want to get particular element from the list, for example the first one, use this:

```
=Filter(Fields!Software.Value,"Office")(0)
```